# How to retrieve values from another class initialization without function to return them manually

Tags: php, class, oop, methods

I'm not sure how to go about this.

I have two classes, LairEngine and RespondEngine.

RespondEngine has certain methods in it that require values that are inside an initialization of LairEngine. 
How do I make an initialization of  RespondEngine automatically grab those values other than having to write methods inside class LairEngine to return values and then pass those as arguments to RespondEngine.

I'm trying to build a framework for telegram bots.

**index.php**

```
require_once('init_lairfw.php');

//Load up LairEngine and RespondEngine 
$engine = new LairEngine;
$respond = new RespondEngine;

$respond->sendText("HEY");
```

**init_lairfw.php**

```
spl_autoload_register(null, false);

spl_autoload_extensions('.mod.php, .lair.php');

function ModuleLoader($class) {
    if(file_exists(strtolower('modules/'.$class.'.mod.php')))   {
        include(strtolower('modules/'.$class.'.mod.php'));
    } 
}

function EngineLoader($class) {
    if(file_exists(strtolower('engine/'.$class.'.lair.php')))   {
        include(strtolower('engine/'.$class.'.lair.php'));
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('ModuleLoader');
spl_autoload_register('EngineLoader');
```

**engine/lairengine.php**

```
class LairEngine {
    private $config;
    private $url;
    private $data;
    private $datatypes;
    //The construct method is executed, and requrired information(incoming data, outgoing data) 
    //is processed and allocated for further use
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->config = json_decode(file_get_contents('config/.Engine'), true);
        $this->url = array(
            "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$this->config['token'],
            "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$this->config['token']."/getFile?file_id=",
            "https://api.telegram.org/file/bot".$this->config['token']."/"
        );

        $this->data = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $this->data = json_decode($this->data, TRUE);
        $this->process();
    }

    //Process the message and find out what kind of message it is
    private function process()
    {
        $k = array_keys($this->data['message']);
        switch($k[4])
        {
            case('reply_to_message'):
                $f=5; $this->dataTypes = array('msg_type' => 'reply');
                $this->dataTypes['reply_to_content'] = array_keys($this->data['message']['reply_to_message'][4]);
                break;

            case('new_chat_title'):
                $f=4; $this->dataTypes = array('msg_type' => 'group_name_change');
                break;

            case('new_chat_photo'):
                $f=4; $this->dataTypes = array('msg_type' => 'group_pic_change');
                break;

            case('forward_from'):
                $f=6; $this->dataTypes = array('msg_type' => 'forward');
                break;

            case('new_chat_participant'):
                $f=null; $this->dataTypes = array('msg_type' => 'new_user');
                break;

            case('left_chat_participant'):
                $f=null; $this->dataTypes = array('msg_type' => 'user_leave');
                break;

            default:
                $f=4; $this->dataTypes = array('msg_type' => 'original');

        }
        $this->dataTypes['msg_content'] = ($f!==null) ?  $k[$f] : null;
    }


    public function returnData()
    {
        $this->data['lair_return'] = $this->dataTypes;
        return $this->data;
    }

    public function returnDataTypes()
    {
        return $this->datatypes;
    }
    public function returnURL()
    {
        return $this->url;
    }

    public function returnchatdata()
    {
        return self::$data['message']['chat'];
    }

    public function throwError($e,$t)
    {
        switch($t)
        {
            case(0): trigger_error($e, E_USER_NOTICE); break;
            case(1): trigger_error($e, E_USER_WARNING); break;
            case(2): trigger_error($e, E_USER_ERROR); break;
        }
    }
}
```

**engine/respondengine.php**

```
class RespondEngine {
    public function sendText($response,$chatID=null,$url=null)
    {
        if(!$chatID)
        {
            //need the value from initalization of LairEngine
        }
        if(!$url)
        {
            //need the value from initalization of LairEngine

        }

        $request = $url."sendMessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=".urlencode($response);
        print_r($request);
        if(file_get_contents($request)) { return true; } else { return false; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't access values via object boundaries without them being public, either by being declared public or by being published by a "getter" method. That is the point of object orientation. If you really are in need of that most likely your architecture is really wrong.

Comment: Okay, can you advise me on how i can rework my architecture. Its still in its basic form, so if you could just give me hints on it i'd appreciate that.

Comment: Certainly we will all try, but for that you will have to show your architecture to us and explain what you are trying to do. We may be good, but we cannot magically _guess_ all that :-)

Comment: @arkascha i've updated the question with links to my code, i'd appreciate it if you could take a quick look :) thanks

Comment: I've put back the code in line, you had used the wrong format codes.

Comment: Instead of speaking of class A and B, could you rephrase your question pointing to the actual classes and methods by name (now the code is there)?

Comment: Done, thanks for being so understanding :)

Comment: Always hard to give an advice by just looking at code. But here it appears to me as if you only need to access those properties private to the LiarEngine as fallback, if the arguments to the `sendText()` method are not available. Certainly that can be done, as said intially by either declaring them public or by implementing getter methods (the preferred way). However I do not like the base idea of those fallbacks. It is a method doing internal magic. Instead, why is the Response Engine instantiated globally? Why not inside some method `LiarEngine::sendResponse()` where the data is available?

Comment: Because, the function basically checks if any argument has been passed for RespondEngine::sendText, if not it grabs the default values. Now if i were to instantiate that class inside LairEngine, i'd have to write wrappers for them inside LairEngine. That just seems messy to me. But i will give this some thinking space and decide.